# Automatically switch to a read-only database when the master database is unavailable

Tags: postgresql, silverstripe

I am trying to find ways to switch between a Master and Slave database (Postgresql). If the Master is not available then SilverStripe will pick it up and switch databases to the Slave (read-only) database.

I was reading through [Sam Minnee's post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/silverstripe-dev/GD_vcU1SaRI) about it and am wondering if there has been any work done on this? Ideally, this would be an automated action.

Comment: Maybe this would help https://github.com/nyeholt/silverstripe-splitdb . Haven't had the need to cluster the db on SS projects yet. Its for mysql so not exactly answering your question :)

Answer (score 0):

you could place code in your _config.php like...

```
global $databaseConfig;

$conn = new mysqli($databaseConfig['server'], $$databaseConfig['username'], $$databaseConfig['password']);
if ($conn->connect_error)
    $otherDB = array(
    "type"      => 'MySQLDatabase',
    "server"    => 'localhost',
    "username"  => 'read_only_user',
    "password"  => 'some_password',
    "path"      => '',
    "database"  => 'other_database'
);
```